# Resources to understand commentary in my tikkun korim

Tags: product-recommendation, torah-reading, commentaries, trop-cantillation

In [the Feldheim Tikkun Korim](http://www.feldheim.com/tikkun-kor-im-simanim-hebrew-only.html), there is some commentary by Sha'arei Mesorah, Ma'aneh Lashon, and Shita Mekubetzet.

From what I can deduce, they are specifically about technicalities of leyning, a mesorah beyond the trope.  Something like "Say these words [high|loudly]" or "Say these words closer together."

I would love to delve into that when preparing leyning, but it's so technical (and often so abbreviated) that it's beyond me.  Where can I find a good resource to understand the technical words and abbreviations used when talking about layning?  I'd ideally like one for English readers, but Hebrew is fine.

Comment: There are many Tikkunim, and this is one edition that I am unfamiliar with. If you are specifically looking for explanations on why certain words are written one way in one place and another way a few psukim later, or why a certain trope is used, I recommend the large green Art Scroll edition (ofhand, I don't know its official name.) It's in English and even though it weighs a lot, it is a nice explanation. Can you specify what types / levels of explanation you are seeking?

Comment: @DanF These are commentaries (from what I can deduce)  specifically about the technicalities of leyning - mesorah that goes beyond trope - "Say this high" or "Say these together". - edited the question to include this information

Comment: Can you list the name, publisher and or ISBN of this book? The topic interests me, offhand. Is this volume available in a bookstore or shul / library?

Comment: @DanF http://www.feldheim.com/tikkun-kor-im-simanim-hebrew-only.html.  But mine is blue.

Comment: The introductions would explain how each is meant to be used... The main one, Shita Mekubetzet, is a set of little memorization tips which may or may not be helpful for keeping straight in your head places where trop is almost the same as a nearby passage but slightly diffferent, etc. It's not anything standard--just an idiosyncratic set of tips worked out by the author.